# Is it a correct sentence when you say "Orange is not a vegetable, and neither is Apple"?

Tags: sentence, construction

Is it a correct sentence when you say “Orange is not a vegetable, and neither is Apple”?

I would like to do the below..
1. I wish to point out the similarity of 2 different subjects (Orange and Apple here).
2. I wish to have the first subject as the first word of the sentence, and the second subject to be the last word of the sentence. Giving it a symmetric appearance. Also I wish to keep the first sentence with 'Something is *not* something..' format.
3. If there is a way to keep the word 'Neither' in the second half of the sentence (as I have in my example), I would prefer that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd modify the sentence to "An orange is not a vegetable, and neither is an apple."

Comment: The argument you'll get is mainly about the (lack of) articles (I want to say "the orange" and "the apple"), but the sentence seems to be technically correct to me, just not terribly idiomatic.

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot! Quick question -  Would it still be correct if I remove ", and" to say.. "An Orange is not a vegetable. Neither is an Apple" ?

Comment: What's wrong with *oranges aren't vegetables, and neither are apples*?

Comment: The confusing thing is that you've capitalized *Orange* and *Apple* as if they are proper nouns, and maybe they are, but they will be immediately heard/read as being common nouns and thus will need an article (or to be referred to in the plural).  It would work just fine with different proper nouns like: "Billy is not a vegetable and neither is John."

Comment: As written, it reads as "The color orange is not a vegetable, and neither is the Apple computer company."

Comment: In the UK there is a telephone provider called Orange, and of course the giant software (etc) company, Apple, is also capitalized, so that sentence is both grammatically and semantically correct!! Ha!

Comment: Otherwise if you're talking about the fruits then Littman's suggestion (top comment) is the best one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would say 
*An orange is not a vegetable, nor is an apple.*

Comment: Can you edit this to add an answer to the question 'Is it a correct sentence when you say “Orange is not a vegetable, and neither is Apple”?' Also, please explain "why."

Comment: "**Neither** an orange **nor** an apple are vegetables"